# Compare submitted textarea with initial value

Tags: php, html, textarea

I want to output an array (from a text-file) into a textarea, let users change it and afterwards save that array back to the text-file.

```
<textarea name="text"><? echo(html_entity_decode(implode("\n", $array))) ?></textarea>
```

Before the array gets stored back to the text-file, I want to make sure, that actually something was changed.

```
if ($_POST['text'] != html_entity_decode(implode("\n", $array))) {
    // SAVE THE TEXT BACK TO THE FILE
}
```

But the above condition always returns `true`, even when no change was submitted.

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything else done with the input while submitting?

Comment: Could you maybe post more of you code ? Maybe on a jsfiddle or just here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try

```
if(strcmp(preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $_POST['text']), html_entity_decode(implode("\n", $array))) != 0){
    // SAVE THE TEXT
}
```

That's getting a bit hard to read, but essentially preg_replace should strip the newline characters out of your POST data for purposes of comparing it to your original array.   Hope this works for you!

Comment: I don't read the text line by line into an array and compare it to the original array. I compare the posted input to the imploded array. So I actually compare an imploded array to an imploded array.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, I edited my answer.   strcmp might be a better solution here, as it's made for comparing strings.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this function. But unfortunately it **always** returns `-14080`.

Comment: You mean always, as in, whether or not the text was changed?

Comment: Can you do a var_dump of your $_POST['text'] and your $array?   Maybe that will give us a hint.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['text'])` returns `string(476) "[…]"` while `var_dump(html_entity_decode(implode("\n", $array)))` returns `string(472) "[…]"`, but the quoted value is identical. If I remove the line breaks from the text, `strcmp(…)` returns `0`, so it has something to do with different interpretation of line breaks...

Comment: the string in $_POST has 4 more characters than the imploded string from your array.   Presumable these characters are the line breaks.   Using preg_replace to strip out the line breaks for your comparison might get you where you want to go.   I'll edit the answer to show what I'd try.

Comment: I also want to compare line breaks, so I ended up using `preg_replace('~\R~u', "\n", htmlentities($_POST['text']))`. This replaces any line breaks (`\r\n` in this case) with `\n`. And finally I can correctly compare the results. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/mark my answer as correct if I was helpful.   Glad you got it figured out.